# reference attribute isn't saving to new instance of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form in a commerce application where users can add an item listing.

In this create#item form, I'd like the user to be able to select (from a dropdown menu) what currency their pricing is in.

(I created a Currency model, views and a controller so the admin can add currency types. (I want the admin to be able to limit currency types).)

Here are the migration files:

```
class CreateCurrencies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :currencies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :symbol

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class AddCurrencyToApartments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :apartments, :currency_id, :integer
    add_index :apartments, :currency_id
  end
end
```

I connected Currency and Item with a belongs_to/has_many relationship in the models. I then implemented a dropdown menu in the create#item form where users can select the currency.

```
<%= f.select( :currency, Currency.all.collect {|u| [ raw(u.symbol), u.id ] }) %>
```

**My question is, why isn't currency_id saving to a new instance of the item model?**

It does seem to show up in the params hash:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...w==", "item"=>{"Name"=>"Test Item", "from_date(1i)"=>"2016", "from_date(2i)"=>"8", "currency"=>"2", "price"=>"7"..... "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Item"}
```

But doesn't actuall save in the commit:

```
0.2ms) begin transaction SQL (1.0ms) INSERT INTO "items" ("name", "from_date", … "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?....) [["name", "Test Item"], ["from_date", "2016-08-11"], ["created_at", "2016-08-11 15:07:50.146172"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-11 15:07:50.146172"]]
```

I also haven't been able to successfully add a currency_id to an apartment from the rails console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: should it be "currency_id"=>"2" instead of "currency"=>"2"?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks for catching my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dropdown menu to <%= f.select( **:currency_id**, Currency.all.collect {|u| [ raw(u.symbol), u.id ] }) %>